# Write text below a specific part of a sentence

Tags: css, javascript, html

I'm looking for to obtain this effect

[image]

that is to place a bracket under a piece of text and then to write text below the said bracket. Is it possible to obtain such an effect using HTML and CSS?

A "primitive" bracket can be obtained by simply adding a bottom-border to the selected text, such as

`The quick <span style="bottom-border: 1px solid">brown fox jumps over the</span> lazy dog.`

But how to add text below the border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does the job, moreover it is also possible to put HTML code below the selected text, an example here

```css
.above {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  }
  .above::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    height: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1.5px currentcolor solid;
    border-top: 0;
    content: "";
  }
  .above .below {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 140%;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<p>The product <span class="above">2 · 2 · 2 <span class="below">2<sup>3</sup></span></span> can be written as power.</p>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could find the x/y-position of the span with Javascript and position another div with an increased y-position? I don't think there will be an out-of-the box css solution to this problem.

Here is a quick example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
        p {font-size: 16px}
        .underline {text-decoration: underline}
        .below_underline {position: absolute; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; display: inline-block; text-align: center}
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){       
        $('.underline').each(function(){
            var position = $(this).position();
            var newElement = '<span class="below_underline">what if we remove this?</span>';
            $(newElement).css('left', position.left).css('top', position.top + 20).css('width', $(this).width() ).appendTo(this);
        });
    }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>The quick <span class="underline">brown fox jumps over the</span> lazy dog.
</body>
</html>
```

It has some flaws, like if the text does not fit on one line etc. etc. but this should give you a good start.

Comment: Do you mean this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element Could you help to implement it?

Comment: @sound-wave edited my answer with an example

Comment: Thanks Vincent! Anyway I found a CSS solution which doesn't require javascript, see answer